# @src Xpath for an Image Attribute

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am in the process of learning Scrapy [Images Pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html) and I indeed could download an image to my local folder with some exceptional assistance from Scrapy experts on stackoverflow.

However, the Xpath is giving me headaches and I cant figure out the xpath selectors for a different set of code. It is given below and I would like to extract the link associated with **data-zoomImage** attribute.

```
<div class="imgWrapper">
<img src="http://img1a.flixcart.com/img/thumb-default.jpg"
     class="productImage  current"
     data-imageId="IMAE3RDWTGGCWGHQ"
     data-src="http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/lenovo-400x400.jpeg"
     data-zoomImage="http://img5a.flixcart.com/image/lenovo-1100x1100.jpeg
</div>
```

I tried to extract the link using the following selectors but with no luck.

```
('//img/@data-zoomImage/@src').extract()
```

Could you all please assist me with this?

UPDATE:

I could download the src attribute with the following selectors

```
('//img[@class="productImage  current"]/@src').extract()
```

I could download the data-src attribute by changing **@src** with **@data-src**. But I am unable to select **data-zoomImage** attribute by the same logic. Any idea about why this could be happening?

Comment: I recommend going through this XPath tutorial: http://www.zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html -- digging a bit into XPath really pays off when it comes to scraping. :)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this might help..

```
     In [26]: t = """ <div class="imgWrapper">
             <img src="http://img1a.flixcart.com/img/thumb-default.jpg"
             class="productImage  current"
             data-imageId="IMAE3RDWTGGCWGHQ"
             data-src="http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/lenovo-400x400.jpeg"
             data-zoomImage="http://img5a.flixcart.com/image/lenovo-1100x1100.jpeg
             </div> """

    In [27]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

    In [28]: sel.xpath('//img[@class="productImage  current"]/@data-zoomimage').extract()
    Out[28]: [u'http://img5a.flixcart.com/image/lenovo-1100x1100.jpeg\n</div>']

    In [29]: sel.xpath('//img[@class="productImage  current"]/@data-zoomImage').extract()
    Out[29]: []
```

don't know why the attribute name changed from **data-zoomImage** to **data-zoomimage**